# 'Hold' UIButton Behaviour - `Touch Cancelled` Control State blocking further control states

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

I have a button on a subview view (for talk sake the subview is a red square) that when the user holds down on the button the red square animates translucent.

I have the button connected to this method:

```
-(IBAction)peekToggle:(id)sendr{        

    NSLog(@"TOGGLE");

    if(self.view.alpha ==1)self.view.alpha = 0.1;   
    else self.view.alpha = 1;       
}
```

Via the behaviours: `touch up inside`, `touch up outside` and `touch down`. so when i hold the button down the red box goes transluscent and when i release my finger it returns to opaque.
This initially  works fine, however if i hold the button down for more than 1 second, the button does not register the `touch up` (release of the finger).

NB:I do have a longPressGestureRecogniser on the parent view (parent of subview not parent of Button) but its not being fired (expected).

Im pretty sure my long press on the button being registered as a `touch cancel` and then invalidating the touch up event.

How can I prevent/work around this?

Can I Stop the `touch Cancel` Firing? (this event seems to fire even if i havant registered the control state) or in the `touch Cancel` event, tell the button to keep/start registering events?

Comment: longPressGestureRecogniser on the parent? then it wont fire since the parent is "behind" the button. Try adding a longPressGestureRecogniser to the button it self. The recogniser will then cascade down the touch to the button if the touch is not recognised.

Comment: I should have been clearer, parent = parent of Subview and not the parent of button and I don't want a long press event, a long press on the button is firing a touch cancel wether its registered event or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Removed the IBActions completely and added `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the **button** with a very short min duration.

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer * recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];    
        recognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.1;  
        [self.peekButton.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        [recognizer release];
```

Then in the selector for the gr, read the gr's state:

```
    - (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{ 

        //1 = start
        if(gestureRecognizer.state==1 || gestureRecognizer.state==3)[self peekToggle];
        //3=end
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think that's your problem, you can try overriding `- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`
 and see if you get any activity there.

Comment: I did this and it fires as expected, seemingly invalidating the touch up as i said in my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate interface to fine-tune when your gesture recognizer gets fired.

Comment: `Touch Canceled` is not a Gesture, and therefore cant be fine tuned though this interface

Comment: It sounds like you think the gesture recognizer is canceling the touch. That sounds like a reasonable hypothesis to me. You can use the delegate interface to make the gesture recognizer ignore your button, and therefore NOT cancel that touch. That's what I'm saying.