# Removing/stop `touchesCancelled` from UIResponder Chain

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

Is there a away to Remove/stop `touchesCancelled` in UIResponder Chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Avoided needed doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003719/hold-uibutton-behaviour-touch-cancelled-control-state-blocking-further-cont) by adding a `UIGestureRecogniser` and reading the `state` property